# laravel time locaze

Tags: laravel

На laravel есть какое нибудь расширение которое локализует время в вид "Сегодня, в 15:40"
"5 минут назад"
и так далее

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$mytime = Carbon\Carbon::now();
echo $mytime->toDateTimeString();
```

Это вывод в обычном формате `Y-m-d H:i:s` но есть много возможностей  прочитать можно в [доках тут](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon) или [тут](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/)

Вот пример:

```
echo Carbon::now()->subSecond(5)->diffForHumans();   // 5 секунд назад
```

**Install:**

```
$ composer require nesbot/carbon
{
    "require": {
        "nesbot/carbon": "~1.14"
    }
}

<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Carbon\Carbon;

printf("Now: %s", Carbon::now());
```

В некоторых  сборках он уже установлен, просто нужно прописать `use`.
Есть еще раздел установки в [документации](https://carbon.nesbot.com/#gettingstarted).

**Подробнее примеры:**

```
echo Carbon::now()->subDays(5)->diffForHumans();               // 5 days ago

echo Carbon::now()->diffForHumans(Carbon::now()->subYear());   // 1 year after

$dt = Carbon::createFromDate(2011, 8, 1);

echo $dt->diffForHumans($dt->copy()->addMonth());              // 1 month before
echo $dt->diffForHumans($dt->copy()->subMonth());              // 1 month after

echo Carbon::now()->addSeconds(5)->diffForHumans();            // 5 seconds from now

echo Carbon::now()->subDays(24)->diffForHumans();              // 3 weeks ago
echo Carbon::now()->subDays(24)->diffForHumans(null, true);    // 3 weeks
```

Comment: Извиняюсь, а как установить это расширение?

Comment: @das изменил ответ.

Comment: Большое спасибо, все заработало. Только остался еще один вопрос) Вот к примеру в контроллере дата выводится так как нужно, а вот когда пытаюсь его заюзать в шаблонизаторе выводит ошибку Class 'Carbon' not found

Comment: @das можно предать в переменной в шаблонизатор из контроллера или подключить в области видимости шаблона. Он просто не видит этот класс и не может использовать.

Comment: Дело в том что у меня перебор массива в шаблоне, а для перебора нужно его использовать именно в шаблоне

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста как подключить в область видимости класс Carbon?

Comment: @des попробуйте конструкцию вида {{  \Carbon\Carbon::createFromTimeStamp()->diffForHumans()‌​ }}

Comment: syntax error, unexpected '‌​' (T_STRING)

Comment: @das попробуйте это {{ Carbon\Carbon::parse($time)->format('d-m-Y i') }}

Comment: Заработало, а как вывести в формате "5 часов назад" и так далее?)) Заранее большое спасибо)

Comment: @das добавил примеры в ответ. подробнее только в доках, ссылки дал в ответ.

Comment: Большое спасибо)) Без вас бы еще неделю разбирался бы